# Mishnah Berurah with Mishnat Sofrim

Tags: product-recommendation, safrus, mishnah-berurah

I was looking on Seforim Center a bit earlier to find an edition of the Chofetz Chaim's hilchot tefillin (in Mishnah Berurah chlk. 1, simanim 25-45). I came across a very nicely typeset edition by Oz Vehadar and I was wondering whether it had the author's *Mishnat Sofrim* which deals with the forms of the Hebrew letters.

Does this, or another nice edition of the M"B include the *Mishnat Sofrim*?

Comment: I've never seen an edition that omits it.

Comment: @DoubleAA both my father's and my grandfather's copies omit it, as do most of the ones in the Harvard Hillel B"M

Comment: @Noach sure it's not just printed in a different place? Some have it by siman 36, some at the end of that chelek of M.B.

Comment: @user6591, I've never checked Siman 36, but I've checked the backs of that chelek and chelek vav, just to be sure.

Comment: If it is the 'shape' of the letters you are looking for , a better sefer has been written by R Silbiger SIL of R Weiss gaavad of yerushalaim.

Comment: Noach It's almost always after 36 in my experience

Comment: Did you try emailing Oz veHadar and asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Oz veHadar edition does have the Mishnas Sofrim as does the edtion published by Moznaim.